# I need some help promises and q library

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I need some help on syntax with `node.js promises`. In readme for `node.js` module called q https://github.com/kriskowal/q is written something I don't understand.

Why do they always write `return` before `promise`?

```
return Q.fcall(eventualAdd, 2, 2);
```

How do I make an asynchronous function with callback into function that returns `promise`? I try

```
function doThis(a,b, callback) { var result = a+ b; setTimeout( callback, 2000, result);}
Q.ncall(doThis, 2,3).then( function(result) { alert(result); });
```

I think after 2000 it must alert with 5 but nothing happens.

Comment: are you running this in nodejs or in the browser? alert doesn't exist in nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason is that in that case they want to return the promise to the caller of the current function.
2. I've done this in my own program and it is done thus:

   - First note that the second argument of `Q.ncall([function], [this], [arguments,...])` is `this`.
   - Secondly note that the arguments to the callback given by `Q.ncall` to the given function are the same as all other node.js callbacks `(error, result)` thus the need to give the callback `null` as the error on success.

     ```
     var Q = require('q');

     function doThis(a,b, callback) { 
       var result = a + b;
       setTimeout(function () { callback(null, result) }, 2000);
     }

     Q.ncall(doThis, null, 2, 3).then(function(result) { console.error(result); });
     ```
   - This code works as you describe; note the differences.