# Javascript function not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, function

I am making a commenting system on my Laravel based CMS.

The logic I am working on currently is when a comment is deleted, I run an ajax call to check how many comments there are and if there is no more comments then I will show a message 'No comments'.

I have everything working, but the last part.

My function is always returning undefined.

The function:

```
function checkCommentCount($id){
  var rootAsset = $('.rootAsset').html();
  $.ajax({
    url: rootAsset+'postcommentcount/'+$id,
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        //return +data.count;
        console.log(data.count);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
      alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
    }
  });
}
```

This correctly logs the count variable returned via JSON. So the PHP side is fine.

However, if try to run the function elsewhere:

```
console.log(checkCommentCount(1648));
```

It always returns undefined. I need to get the function to a return a number value so I can do my check.

The console log works fine in the function, but if I change that to:

```
return data.count;
```

Then the function will return undefined...

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous javascript, hold on let me find the dupe.

Comment: It will return undefined since ajax request will be delayed always, use `q` library to deal with it [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642459/i-need-some-help-promises-and-q-library)

Comment: Your function will always return `undefined` as you don't `return` anything. Though I am sure that will not be the only problem.

Comment: @Xotic750 I think you missed reading the last few lines of the question.

Comment: You could make the call synchronous...

Comment: That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Jamiec Nope, don't think so. He doesn't return anything from his function, though that will not solve his problem of not understanding asynchronous code.

Comment: Unless you're returning the whole promise from the function, you're not going to be returning anything - you'd be using a callback.

Comment: @Xotic750 There is both the `return` line commented out in the big code block and the comment that if he changes the `console.log` to a `return data.count` it doesnt work.

Comment: @Jamiec That would be the `return` for the `success` function and not for `checkCommentCount` function which has no `return`, but like I said that would not help him anyway; he needs to use a callback or return a promise.

Comment: I think keeping your return statement after the ajax call will work . Doing it inside success will not work .

Comment: @TusharRaj by using AJAX synchronously he could, but perhaps you should read the answer that this is marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score -2):

Your ajax call is asynchronous. This means that your JavaScript function returns nothing, and later on when the ajax call finishes your success/error callback is called.